# how to return a value from JsonResult to the bootstrap fileinput

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc-3, file-io, bootstrap-file-upload

Good evening, I'm using the api bootstrap fileinput and I wonder if you can return a value with ContetResult and uses it in my View.

my Test Controller method ContentResult (just a test):

```
public ContentResult upload()
{

    string name = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < Request.Files.Count; i++) 
    { 
        HttpPostedFileBase file = Request.Files[i];
        name = file.FileName;
    }

     return Content("{\"name\":\"" + name + "\"}", "application/json");

}
```

and my View:

```
<input id="input-701" name="kartik-input-701[]" type="file" multiple=true class="file-loading" />
<input type="text" class="file_name" />

<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#input-upload").fileinput({ 'showUpload': true, 'previewFileType': 'any' });

    $("#input-701").fileinput({

        uploadUrl: '@Url.Action("upload", "Home")', // server upload action
        uploadAsync: false,
        maxFileCount: 50,


        sucess: function (e, data) {

            $('.file_name').html(data.result.name);

        }
    });


</script>
```

so I want to do something like this illustrative atributte: sucess

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

Just Insert value in textbox

```
  $('.file_name').val(data.result.name);
```